# In SQL Server, can you INSERT multiple records based off of calculations?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have several tables that I am doing some calculations on to determine how many of each type of record to insert into another table.  For example, the main entities are County, Members, Plans.  When I finish running my calculations I end up with something like:

- Insert 25 [County A] + [Plan 1] records into table
- Insert 15 [County A] + [Plan 2] records into table
- Insert 10 [County A] + [Plan 3] records into table
- Insert 15 [County A] + [Plan 4] records into table
- Insert 25 [County A] + [Plan 5] records into table
- Insert 63 [County B] + [Plan 1] records into table
- Insert 47 [County B] + [Plan 3] records into table
- Insert 19 [County B] + [Plan 4] records into table

The INSERTS would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO Assign (ID, CountyID, PlanID)
VALUES (NEWID(), 'A', 1), (NEWID(), 'A', 1), ..., (NEWID(), 'A', 1) -- 25 times
INSERT INTO Assign (ID, CountyID, PlanID)
VALUES (NEWID(), 'A', 2), (NEWID(), 'A', 2), ..., (NEWID(), 'A', 2) -- 15 times
```

etc

I am looking for a way to build these INSERT statements from within a stored procedure that:

- Don't use a cursor and/or while loop
- Does not do individual inserts, want a bulk insert approach
- Uses a CTE?  (Not required but who knows)

All of this information is stored in a temp table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE #holding (countyID CHAR(2), planID INT, perCountyPlan INT)

SELECT * FROM #holding ORDER BY countyID, planID
A  1  25
A  2  15
A  3  10
A  4  15
A  5  25
B  1  63
B  3  47
B  4  19
C .......
etc
```

Any ideas how to form an INSERT based on the #history table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have perCountyPlan<= 2048, please try this. Otherwise, you need build you own number table

```
WITH num AS (
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P' 
)
INSERT INTO Assign (ID, CountyID, PlanID)
SELECT  NEWID(),h.countyID, h.planID
FROM    #holding h
INNER JOIN num n 
    ON n.number < h.perCountyPlan
```

Comment: I may have to build my own number table but I can do that in increments of 2048 based on the master..spt_values table.  And damn - slicker than snot!  Thanks!